# MS Access: UPDATE syntax error

Tags: sql-update, ms-access-2003

```
UPDATE sentences SET  text = 0 WHERE  text = 17
```

What will there occures when updating column participated in both SET and WHERE parts of query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue here. All the row whose `text` value is `17` will have a `text` value of `0` when the UPDATE is executed. But, as `text` is a keyword in Access, you should enclose it with square brackets:

```
UPDATE sentences SET [text] = 0 WHERE [text] = 17
```

Comment: Column "text" is varchar. Query "UPDATE sentences SET numbercount = 0 WHERE  text = 17" executes rightly.

Comment: So, you have an error? If yes, what is the error? Or the table is not modified?

Comment: Error is syntax. It occurs after SET when updating column "text" haves in condition of updating.

Comment: `text` is a keyword for MS Access. Can you try to enclose it between square brackets: `UPDATE sentences SET [text] = 0 WHERE [text] = 17`

Comment: Oh, yes. Now, "update sentences set   txt  = 0 where txt = 17" is right. There were error because "text" is MS Access keyword. Thank you, Teetoo!